# Including jar files in class path

Tags: java, jar, batch-file, classpath

I m running a java program from a batch file which refences some external jar files .How do i include those jar files in my batch file.Please help

Answer (score 17):

Look at the Sun's official documentation: [Setting the class path](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) to understand your options.

A quick way would be just to include your JAR(s) after the `-cp`:

#### on Windows

```
java -cp C:\java\MyClasses\myclasses.jar;C:\java\MyClasses\myclassesAnother.jar utility.myapp.Cool
```

#### on Linux/Unix

```
java -cp /opt/thirdparty/myclasses.jar:/opt/thirdparty/myclassesAnother.jar utility.myapp.Cool
```

Comment: what directory we need to be in, where is you my map

Answer (score 6):

You need to set classpath http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/classpath.html. E.g.,

```
java -cp file1.jar;file2.jar yourApp
```

or if your jar-files are located in directory `lib/`

```
java -cp lib/* yourApp
```

Comment: I'm not sure that `lib/*.jar` will work -- the link you included says that the right syntax is `lib/*`, which will match all files ending with `.jar` or `.JAR` in that folder.

Answer (score 2):

Not to bother with -classpath parameter you could put references to the jar files into the manifest.mf of your application JAR, if it's you application of course.

[Adding Classes to the JAR File's Classpath](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I dont know others IDE, but works with me on Eclipse.
Right click on your project, select

> Properties/ Java Build Path/ Libraries/ Classpath/ Add External JARs...

Then choose whatever files you need :v

Answer (score 1):

You have to fill the Class-Path parameter of the manifest file of the JAR. The standard documentation explains that very well.

Answer (score 0):

When running a jar or class file specify classpath option

Comment: If you're running a jar using `-jar` the classpath option is ignored.