# Hibernate: No Suitable Driver Found when run in Servlet

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets

So, right now I'm doing my first webapp. This is something relatively crude on the web side of things. A few servlets and JSP pages, coupled with Hibernate and database access. No frameworks, MVC, any of that (Yes, it's all very important, but this is just a quick test of how well I understand Servlets before I start working on the bigger things).

Anyway, I'm having a problem with Hibernate. The weird thing is, it's got to have something to do with Hibernate's interaction with the servlet/server.

Let me explain: I have a test class (literally a class called Test) that I simply used to test my ORM mapping annotations. It works perfectly. Like 110% perfectly. Connection is made, database is manipulated, etc. This is the code for it, again just a simple test (ClassesServiceImpl is a service with a Hibernate SessionFactory inside it):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassesServiceImpl service = (ClassesServiceImpl) ClassesServiceImpl.getInstance();

    Student student = service.createStudent("Bob", "Saget", LocalDate.of(1988,10,26), 11);
    Course math = new Course("Math", "Anderson", 5);
    student.addCourse(math);
    service.saveStudent(student);

    service.close();
}
```

The code I just pasted works. No problem whatsoever, I can go into MySQL directly after running this and the changes are there.

Problem is, when I try to do the exact same thing in a Servlet, I get an exception. Here is the code:

```
private ClassesService service;

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    List<Student> studentList = service.getAllStudents();
    req.setAttribute("studentList", studentList);
    req.getRequestDispatcher("/studentlist.jsp").forward(req, resp);
}

@Override
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    service = ClassesServiceImpl.getInstance();
}
```

When I run that Servlet, I get a Hibernate ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]. The stack trace has a chain of causes, that refer to an error calling DriverManager#getConnection, and ultimately ends with a SQLException: No sutiable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/classes.

I'm pasting the full stack trace below. I just don't understand why this is happening. It works PERFECTLY when I'm not using it on the server, but when I do use it on the server this happens.

Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:244)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:692)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
io.craigmiller160.classes.servlet.StudentListServlet.doGet(StudentListServlet.java:29)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
root cause

org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling DriverManager#getConnection
org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:115)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:101)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:123)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverManagerConnectionCreator.java:37)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:89)
org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:692)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
io.craigmiller160.classes.servlet.StudentListServlet.doGet(StudentListServlet.java:29)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
root cause

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/classes
java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverManagerConnectionCreator.java:34)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:89)
org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:692)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
io.craigmiller160.classes.servlet.StudentListServlet.doGet(StudentListServlet.java:29)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
```

EDIT:

Some folks mentioned that the driver needs to be in my classpath. Well, it is. Remember what I said: it works when I'm not running it in a servlet. The test code I pasted above works fine. It's only when I run it in the servlet that the problem happens.

```
<!-- MySQL ConnectorJ -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.36</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: That means that the MySQL JDBC driver is not in the classpath (i.e. under WEB-INF/lib).

Comment: you should have driver jar in your libs

Comment: I do. It works when I don't run it in the servlet. Only in the servlet does it say it can't find the driver. I just pasted the Maven dependency I'm using into my question.

Answer (score 1):

> No sutiable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/classes

This Error Simply states that MySQL-JDBC Driver is not in your class path when you are executing in Web Application.

- Make Sure jar file exist in WEB-INF/lib directory and is added in
  class path - [Follow
  this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463354/how-to-put-a-jar-in-classpath-in-eclipse)

You didn't face any problem in Simple Java Program because that Jar File is already added in your Windows/Linux OS Classpath - [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084926/including-jar-files-in-class-path)

Comment: Check my edit. I have the driver in my classpath. It's included in my Maven dependencies. Again, like I said, I can do these same operations in my test class and it works fine, it's only when I try and run it in the servlet that I have a problem.